# Convert a string with a particular pattern to a checkbox

Tags: android, string, checkbox

I am trying to convert a string with a special pattern to checkboxes. The **pattern** is the following: **[ ]** and **[x]**. How do I make it looks like this

Here are the patterns in strings

[image: Converted edit text]

Here is **what I want to make it look like:**

[image: Converted edit text]

I want to create a checkbox where the string pattern is **[ ]** and a checked box where string pattern is **[x]**.

I have tried to look for the pattern in a string using **something.contains("[ ]")**, it works but I do not know how to make it look like a checkbox/checkedbox.

Any solution to it?

Comment: just use different icons based on either `[]` or `[x]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `.replace()`

```
text = stringTxt!!.replace("[ ]", "☐").replace("[x]", "✓")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, .contains can be used to find the strings with the pattern. For check mark, you could use something like:

```
//To check
txtView.setText("[✓]"+" remaining text...");
//To uncheck
txtView.setText("[ ]"+" remaining text...");
```

You can add this to an onClickListener and flip between check and uncheck states.